# Insert values and SELECT from another table

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a table where I want to combine some manual values AND add some from another table.

What am I missing in the query below?

```
INSERT INTO `table1`  (event_date, country, transaction_id, item_id, item_name, item_quantity, unique_orders, item_revenue)
VALUES ('20230807', 'USA', '00000000000', 'GL000000000', 'Product', 2, 2, 100),('20230807', 'CAN', '00000000000', 'GL000000000', 'Product', 4, 4, 200)

SELECT
country,transaction_id, items.item_id as item_id
,items.item_name as item_name
,SUM(items.quantity) as item_quantity
,COUNT(event_timestamp) as unique_orders
,SUM(items.item_revenue) as item_revenue
FROM(
SELECT
event_name, items, ecommerce.transaction_id AS transaction_id, event_timestamp,geo.country AS country
FROM
`table2`,
UNNEST (items) AS items
WHERE
event_name = 'purchase'
AND items.item_id LIKE '%GL000000001%'
)
GROUP BY item_id, country, transaction_id,item_name)
```